# Backbone View: $el not working as expected

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have defined a View as follows:

```
var BookView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    className: "bookContainer",

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html("Hello World"); // Problem is here
        return this;
    }
});

var bookView = new app.BookView({});
```

The problem is, `Hello World` is not getting added in the specified `div` which I reference using `this.$el`.

Instead, if I do this(in `render()` method):

```
$(".bookContainer").html("Hello World");
```

it works fine. Why isn't `this.$el` referencing to `$(".bookContainer")`?

Note: If I log `this.$el`, I get following object:

```
[div.bookContainer, context: div.bookContainer]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand how `tagName` and `className` work. From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el):

> **el** `view.el`
>   [...]
>   `this.el` can be resolved from a DOM selector string or an Element; otherwise it will be created from the view's `tagName`, `className`, `id` and `attributes` properties.

So the `tagName` and `className` properties are used to *create* the `el`, not find it in the DOM. If you want to bind your view to an existing element, use `el`:

```
el: '.bookContainer'
```

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of this. After removing the original `div.bookContainer` from my index.html, it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert `bookView` into the page.

When you call `bookView = new app.BookView({});` you have an instance of a `Backbone.View` that contains the html of:

```
<div class="bookContainer">
  Hello World
</div>
```

However, this element has not yet been inserted into the DOM. You still need to do that. As an example:

```
bookView = new app.BookView({});

// put the bookview element into the dom
$('body').html(bookView.el);
```

The reference to `el` is the element of the `Backbone.View`, documentation for this can be found [here](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add this in my post, but I already have this in my html. <div class="bookContainer">

</div>

Comment: @akshayKhot, I realized that the moment I read mu's answer, he's got the answer you're looking for.